# What does this error mean and why does it appear?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that creates and declares different types. But every time I write 'create type' or 'declare type' I get this error:

> ERROR line 4, col 10, ending_line 4, ending_col 18, Found 'recipient', Expecting:  (    .    @   or   %   or  ..  :=  DEFAULT  NOT  NULL  or   ;

I use Oracle 10 and these are the first lines of the procedure. The error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ACTIVITE_PROD.NOTIF_NEW_HOLIDAY(v_USER_ID INTEGER,     v_DURATION NUMBER, v_WEEK INTEGER, v_YEAR INTEGER) IS

-- this line causes the error
create type recipient as object (firstname varchar2, lastname varchar2, email varchar2);

-- this line also causes an error if modified and set first
declare
    type recipients_list is table of recipient;

    admins recipients_list := recipients_list();
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Oracle Documentation [Using PL/SQL With Object Types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm)

> Currently, you cannot define object types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package. You can define them interactively in SQL*Plus using the SQL statement CREATE TYPE.